# Input value not accepting object on vue js

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have input type *text* on my vue js application.

this is my code:

```
<input type="text" v-model="answer[index]" >
```

updated code:

```
<table>
    <tr v-for="(question_overall, index) in questions">
        <td>
            {{ question_overall.question }}
            <div>
                <input type="text" :value="{id: question_overall.id , answer:  ??}" v-model="answer[index]" >
            </div>
            {{ answer[index] }}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

data: function () {
     return {
        questions: [],
        answer:{
            id: null,
            answer: null,
        },
     }
},
```

and I want if I echo out the v-model like this:

```
{{ answer[index] }}
```

the output will be:

```
{ "id": 1, "answer": "the value of this answer is from what I type in" }
```

Can you help me on my problem? thank you.

Comment: What problem are you having? Your code is doing exactly what you're asking...

Comment: yes, but i want to generate the output like this {id: 1, answer: "what I type in"}

Answer (score 0):

> Please take a closer look to [vue.js docs](https://vuejs.org)

How to use v-model:

```
<input type="text" v-model="text.answer" />
```

the script:

```
export default {
  data: () => ({
    text: {
       id: 1,
       text: ''
    }
  })
}
```

Another way to use v-model

the script:

```
export default {
  data: () => ({
    text: {
       id: 1,
       text: ''
    }
  }),
  methods: {
    value_changing(event) {
     this.text = event.target.value
    }
  }
}
```

If you want a v-model with for loop take a look [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xo1feu7d/)

Comment: sorry for not being very specific I have a loop of questions and the id is from the id of question from database. how can I pass the id? i will update my code.

Comment: Why do you need an id in the input?

Comment: @Lara ok i made a fiddle for you using v-model with v-for.I updated my answer

Comment: If i helped you please appreciate my help

Comment: yes. thank you. how can I mark this question solved?

Comment: In my answer above you have 3 buttons.If you hover over them you will see for what are those